# c# itext 7 Wrap texto en una celda

Tags: c#, itext

Quisiera saber si existe la forma de contener texto en una celda.

Por ejemplo quiero poner este texto  en una celda

> Este Texto va en la celda

pero se corta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Table table = new Table(1);
table.AddCell(cellLeft.Clone(false).Add(new Paragraph("Este Texto va en la celda").SetMultipliedLeading(1.5f)).SetFontSize(4.3f).SetWidth(100).SetHeight(Measures.CentimeterToUserPoint(200))
```

y quiero que quede algo así, sin que se corte el texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sobre que estas trabajando?

Comment: A que te refieres? lenguaje c# con la librería itext7

Comment: sobre winforms, asp net, wpf o xamarin?

Comment: Es sobre Wpf :)

Comment: no entiendo bien que queires hacer, es como el efecto placeholder de campos de texto de html o algo parecido? no puedo ver tu imagen

Comment: Quiere aplicar una propiedad para que el texto se ajuste, y no se corte. Placeholder no es para que tenga texto de fondo hasta que escribes?

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta

Comment: deberias de hacer mas grande el campo y darle a prueba y error, he trabajando con itextsharp pero es una lata, no puedo ayudarte mas, suerte :)